# Problem with iPad staying connected to wireless access point as signal strength decreases

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ipad, wireless-access-point, connection

I'm not really a networking guy, but I need to solve a problem with some WiFi-only iPad 2s that I intend to deploy at work. I just installed six wireless access points (Cisco E2000s) throughout the building. The APs are configured with DD-WRT [according to the specs in the DD-WRT documentation](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point).

All of the APs have the same SSID and the same key. They use three different channels, and I tried not to position two APs with the same channel near each other.

I think I have decent coverage throughout the whole building, but there's still a problem.  When I walk around with an iPad, I go through periods when the signal is really weak, and the connection is degraded. What I *think* is happening is this: the iPad stays connected to a given AP, until the signal gets so weak that the connection is dropped altogether. At that point, the iPad looks for another, stronger signal to connect to. As I walk further away from that new AP, the signal is again degraded, and the cycle continues.

Is there anything I can do to force the iPads to drop a connection *before* it gets very weak? Seems like this is a problem that has already been solved somewhere by someone.

There aren't many parameters to change on the iPads, but maybe there is something I can do on the APs?  Should I be using a different configuration from the one I actually used?  If not, are there any settings that can be tweaked?

Comment: Super User is not for questions about mobile devices as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Are DD-WRT / wireless networking off-topic?

Comment: So long as the devices are attached or connect with computer hardware, it's on topic @mar